# Need help to solve this mapreduce code

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

```
Below is the data

c1         p1      q1      d1

c2         p2      q2      d2
```

Need output like-  if customer has purchase p1 it should give `flag as 1` else it should give `flag 0`. there are millions of customer and millions of product Below is the required output. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

```
c1 p1 q1 d1 1

c1 p2 q1 d1 0

c2 p2 q2 d2 1

c2 p1 q2 d2 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it with just a mapside logic, sample code for your reference:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String line = value.toString();
    NullWritable value = NullWritable.get();
    String tokens[] = line.split("<your delim>");
    if (tokens[1] == "p1") {
        line = line + "<your delim>" + "1";
    } else if (tokens[1] == "p2") {
        line = line + "<your delim>" + "0";
    }
    context.write(newText(line), value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But here its not only p1 and p2, it is just an example. it has million of products and millions of customer.

Comment: Sure @Som7 I am ready to help. Can you elaborate more on the problem statement, I mean , how you want to handle the flag status for more than two products , will it be still binary (1 or 0)  or any other constraints?

Comment: Based on the problem statement , we can discuss and choose an appropriate design pattern  in MR and go a head to implement the solution.

Comment: Thanks Addy. I would like to get.All the product purchase by customer (c1) to flag as 1 and product not purchase flag as 0 . for example customer (c1) has purchase product p1,p2,p4,p10,p11..... this should be flag 1. and not purchase product p3,p5,p6,p7 should be flag as 0.  I think the approach should be first identify all product. then do a check what product bought by customer and flag it accordingly.  Hope its clear.

Comment: Half way @Som7 .But still more clarifications. one which factor (column) do you decide if customer purchased a product? . As per my understanding you can map customer details in mapper with KV pair as (c1,<rest of row>) and in reducer , collect the group of products purchased by each customer , iterate over that list and implement your logic in reducer and then write back with conext.write(K,V) with your desired output. Implementing business logic in reducer is not so preferable but in your case it should be ok .